# Can we add an empty Table in From clause

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

In my SQL query from clause there is a table (table 1)I have noticed if this table is empty my whole query results null.Also if  i do not use this table in where and select clause.
What is reason behind this and how to prevent this.

> select     ps.ProductName     from
> productsale ps,StockTransfer dtc
> where
> ps.productcode = '010134600223'
> and  ps.productcode=
>
> ```
>   (case when  ps.productcode=dtc.productcode then
> ```
>
> dtc.productcode else ps.productcode
> end)

***This query works fine if I not add StockTransfer  table in form clause(If StockTransfer  table is empty) else it works fine.***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do a cross join. That means that for every row in Table1 you will get all rows in Table2. So if Table1 has 4 rows and Table2 has 2 rows you will get 8 rows in the result set (4*2=8). If Table2 contains 0 rows you will get 0 rows in result set (4*0=0).

To fix this you need to add a join condition.

Comment: Why i need a join.As i am not selecting from  table1.That is empty.

Comment: @Zain, you *are* selecting from table1 and table2. `select *` means that you want all columns from included tables and that you add table1 to the `from` clause means that you want to use table1 in the query. If you don't want it you need to remove it.

Comment: @Zain – I have explained why you get the result you get using the kind of join you use. You need to explain what you want the query to do, preferably with some sample data and expected output. As the query is now you can replace it with `select ps.ProductName
from productsale as ps
where ps.productcode = '010134600223'`

Answer (score 2):

Depends on how you did your join.

If you do

```
select * from tablea join tableb on tablea.id=tableb.id
```

and tableb is empty, then nothing could result as nothing was there.

left or right joins depending on which is the empty table, work to do exactly that.

left join will return all data in the first table and any data from the second table that matches so

```
select * from tablea left join tableb on tablea.id=tableb.id
```

would return in short, all but just tablea data, because thats all there is (but any additional fields you asked for from tableb, but obviously no data as there was none)